# Editing settings file for maven

Tags: java, xml, maven

I have maven 3.5.4 and java 1.8 running on my Windows 7 machine. I may need to make some edits to the settings.xml file for maven, however I am not able to locate it. My maven installation folder is as follow: `C:\Users\username\.m2`. I am not able to locate `settings.xml` in any of the subfolders inside this folder.

Comment: The settings.xml file also known as the config file for MAVEN is located in the Maven installation directory – in a folder called conf – and is named settings.xml.Check out this link https://www.baeldung.com/maven-local-repository

Comment: Don't modify the settings.xml in the Maven installation. See below for the correct answer.

Comment: I am getting an error when I run mvn archetype:generate . It says:

No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\user\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]. I thought I would need to make some changes to the settings.xml file to overcome this problem. Since I can't find that file, is there any other way I can solve this? Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a default settings file in `C:\users\user\.m2`

Settings.xml is not mandatory. If it is absent, then Maven still works without custom settings.

You can also call maven with a specific `settings.xml` file by using `-s` or `--settings` options. For example:

```
mvn -s mySettings.xml clean install
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always run the mvn command with debug specified in any directory and in the message it will show you which settings.xml files he's using

**Command:** `mvn -X`

**Output:**

```
...
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from C:\tools\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin\..\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\{username}\.m2\settings.xml
...
```